# How to open linked pdf file in full screen in beamer?

Tags: beamer, hyperref, pdf, adobe, href

The following is the code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {\usetheme{Madrid}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\href[pdfnewwindow]{sample.pdf}{try}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This works fine. I am using Adobe reader on Windows 10 os. When I click try, the pdf file gets opened in new window. I want to open the `sample.pdf` file in `full-screen` or `presentation` mode. What option is there in href for that?

Comment: I don't think that this is possible unless you use some java script. Or if you have access to the sample.pdf you could set there PageMode in the catalog to FullScreen (with the pdfpagemode key).

Comment: With the code from your deleted question I get sample.pdf in full screen mode. So use this with some non adobe viewer?

Comment: It works in non-adobe reader (when full screen is already active for the current file). I am looking solution for Adobe reader.

Comment: As an untested alternative, if you do the presentation yourself, you could try to open the second pdf in full-screen before you start and then use alt-tab to switch away from it. Then during the presentation, instead of clicking the link, you can alt-tab back into the other file, which (again, untested) should then still be fullscreen.